# Css horizontal nested menu not working correctly

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this website that has a wordpress generated menu that makes a horizontal menu with a submenu that has subcategories.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/79RKd/3/

Hover to *properties* > *property search* and then to *featured listings*. The submenu of property search will not dissapear thing that is very annoying.

Also hovering over the suboptions of property search and then back to featured listings will deactivate the link of featured linistings ans the submenu will not dissapear.

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
<div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-33"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-612" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-612"><a>Properties</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-660" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-660"><a>Property Search</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-663" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-663"><a href="#">Basic Search</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-664" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-664"><a href="#">Advanced Search</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-209" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-209"><a href="#">Featured Listings</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-632" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-632"><a href="#">Mortgage Calculator</a></li>
</ul>
</li>


</ul></div></nav>
```

CSS

```
.main-navigation ul#menu-main-menu li.menu-item:hover ul.sub-menu{display:block;}
ul.sub-menu{width:185px;position:absolute;left:0;z-index:6;margin:0;padding:0;}
ul.sub-menu li{background-color:#00314f;}
ul.sub-menu > li:hover > ul > li{background-color:#00314f;display:block;width:185px;position:relative;top:-62px;left:185px;z-index:6;border-left:1px solid #ccc;margin:0;padding:0;}
ul.sub-menu > li{float:none;border-bottom:1px solid #e2e2e2;position:relative;}
.main-navigation ul.sub-menu,.main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul,ul.sub-menu li > ul li,.sub-menu ul li ul{display:none;}
.menu{height:60px;margin:0 auto;}
.menu ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
.menu li{display:block;position:relative;float:left;height:60px;padding:0 0 0 2px;}
.menu a{display:block;height:36px;background:none;letter-spacing:-1px;font:18px/19px Helvetica, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;padding:20px 20px 0;}
.menu a:hover{border-bottom:1px solid #c5c5c5;text-decoration:none;}
.menu .active a{border-bottom:4px solid #E1E9E2;text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: Ok for jsFiddle.... but maybe you could save our eyes, beautyfing code before post it..... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/79RKd/4/)**

**Add two lines of CSS to fix position**

```
.main-navigation ul#menu-main-menu li.menu-item:hover ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu{left: 185px; top: 0;}
.main-navigation ul#menu-main-menu li.menu-item:hover ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu li{top:0; left:0;}
```

Hope this Helps!